# MySQL автоматическое обновление записи через заданное время

Tags: mysql

В таблице есть ячейка в timestamp, в котором указана дата, когда необходимо обновить эту запись (например, изменить статус).
Можно ли при помощи MySQL сделать это автоматически?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE EVENT update_status
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
COMMENT 'Update Status from 1 to 2 after 1 week.'
DO
UPDATE `table`
SET `status` = 2
WHERE creation_datetime < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
  AND `status` = 1;
```

!!! Не забыть убедиться, что планировщик не отключен, и включить его, если он не запущен:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Но лучше откорректировать строку запуска и/или файл конфигурации. Подробнее см. [тут](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_event-scheduler) и [тут](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-configuration.html#events-event-scheduler-option).